# How to import non-core npm modules in Angular 2 e.g. (to use an encryption library)?

Tags: encryption, npm, angular

In my Angular 2 app (SystemJS module manager, Typescript as scripting language) I need to import a npm module to handle encryption (either Crypto-JS;Forge-JS or any other serving the purpose)

In the case of **CryptoJS**, after installing it via **npm install** * I tried by adding:

```
  <script src="node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"></script>
```

in **index:html**.

The in my service (**app/services/my-service.service.ts**) I import it via

```
  import {CryptoJS} from 'node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js' // or /aes.js --> same issue
```

However the import doesn't work correctly as for example

```
 console.log(CryptoJS);
```

prints **undefined**.

I also tried to add the module path in

```
 System.config({
     // ...
     map: {
        CryptoJS
    }
}
```

and importing it in my service by

```
 import {CryptoJS} from 'cryptoJs';
```

While I'm not sure **what I should actually put in SystemJS config**, none of the solutions I tried worked.

**EDIT** I also tried...

```
// import ... as to overcome no default export
import * as CryptoJS from 'node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js';
```

but then

```
 console.log(CryptoJS.);
```

gives no AES/whatever method (my editor usually advices which methods I could use via auto-completion)

**EDIT 2** now thanks to Thierry and PierreDuc contribution it is clear that typings and module import are unlinked concepts.

However neither of them is working. This is what I've done:

I downloaded [CryptoJS typings file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/raw/master/cryptojs/cryptojs.d.ts), put it in typings/cryptojs/cryptojs.d.ts

Then I added

```
  /// <reference path="cryptojs/cryptojs.d.ts"/>
```

to **typings/main.d.ts**

Then I added cryptojs in SystemJS's map config:

```
   cryptojs: "node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"
```

Finally I tried to import cryptojs in my service by

```
  import CryptoJS from 'cryptojs'
```

As far as I see there are 2 issues:

- typings are not loaded since there is no autocompletion when I try to import the module (I also tried to restart the Angular 2 app). Perhaps I didn't understand how to import external typings?
- the module is not loaded anyway, I can see that by console.log(cryptojs) (nothing is printed, not even undefined; unlikely my previous attempts)

**EDIT 3**

Finally I got the import working thanks to Thierry and PierreDuc advice (not sure what went wrong on the first place).
However I still have issues with typings.

Despite I put

```
  /// <reference path="../../typings/cryptojs/cryptojs.d.ts"/>
```

directly in my service, when I write

```
  import CryptoJS from 'cryptojs';
```

just below that line, I get no autocompletion and when I start Angular 2 app over by **npm start** ; I get the following error and the app doesn't start

```
  app/services/user.service.ts(6,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'cryptojs'.
```

**NOTE**: If I add cryptojs to SystemJS config (but not a ) and then write (without any import)

```
console.log(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key123').toString());
```

it just works but I'd rather solve the typings + import issues.

Comment: add [CryptoJS Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/cryptojs/cryptojs.d.ts) to your typings, and the `crypto-js.js` to your `index.html` and you should be good to go. Don't forget to add a `/// <reference path="typings/cryptojs/cryptojs.d.ts"/>` to your bootstrap file

Comment: Any of the answers here are working for the latest angular version by today?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this since the library is CommonJS-compliant in your main HTML file:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    cryptojs: 'node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js'
  },
  (...)
});
```

and import it this way:

```
import CryptoJS from 'cryptojs';
```

For the compilation part, you can follow the Pierre's suggestion.

**Edit**

I made some tests and here is the way to do.

- Install typings for crypto-js:

  ```
  $ typings install --ambient crypto-js
  ```
- Include the corresponding typings into your ts file:

  ```
  /// <reference path="../typings/main/ambient/crypto-js/crypto-js.d.ts"/>

  import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
  (...)
  ```
- Configure the library in SystemJS in your main HTML file:

  ```
  <script>
    System.config({
      map: {
        'crypto-js': 'node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js'
      },
      (...)
    });
  </script>
  ```
- Import the library into your ts files:

  ```
  import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
  ```

Comment: Ah yes, this way you don't have to add it to your `index.html`. I keep forgetting that. But as you mentioned, for compilation/code hinting, you need the `d.ts` file. This is not included in the `node_module`

Comment: What do you mean with 'you have to'? `SystemJS` will import the needed library right, if you place it in `map`. No need to add it as script to the `index.html` I thought. (fyi, remove or add an quote (') to the map name of cryptojs :))

Comment: If the SystemJS config is defined in the `index.html` file, you have to ;-) Otherwise no... Thanks for pointing the typo out! I updated my answer...

Comment: But I agree with you, you should externalize this config ;-)

Comment: Thanks Thierry and PierreDuc. I still have same issue. please see my updated question (EDIT 2)

Comment: You're welcome! You should use the following to import: `import CryptoJS from 'cryptojs'` and not `import {} from 'cryptojs'`

Comment: that's what I actually did. my mistake just here

Comment: Ah okay ;-) Can you see the corresponding request in the Network tab of dev tools?

Comment: sorry for the late response. actually not, not even in "resources" -> node_modules/

Comment: I just made a test and if I print in the console the `CryptoJS` object from my response, it's not null: `Object {lib: Object, enc: Object, algo: Object, x64: Object, mode: Object…}AES: ObjectDES: ObjectEvpKDF: (password, salt, cfg)HmacMD5: (message, key)HmacRIPEMD160: (message, key)HmacSHA1: (message, key)HmacSHA3: (message, key)HmacSHA224: (message, key)...`

Comment: thanks again:now it works almost perfectly.  The only issue is that typings are apparently wrong since **CryptoJS.AES(pars)** is a valid typing but not a valid function whereas **CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(pars)** is a valid function but not a valid typing. I'll accept the answer to thank for the effort. Maybe you can help me fixing this last issue as it basically prevent the Angular app to start when I restart it

Comment: thanks @Thierry. which repository shall I opened the issue to?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get CryptoJS working in an Angular2 project generated with angular-cli with the following steps/configuration:

**bash**

```
npm install crypto-js --save
typings install crypto-js --ambient --save
```

**angular-cli-build.js**

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      /* ... */
      'crypto-js/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

**system.config.ts**

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'crypto-js': 'vendor/crypto-js'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'crypto-js': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js',
    format: 'cjs'
  }
};
```

**some.component.ts**

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

This was the only setup that I could get working for both a regular build and a `-prod` build.  I realize this question wasn't specifically about angular-cli, but figured I'd answer it anyways in case it helps someone else.

Comment: thanks for the answer. in the end installing the updated typings (they fixed them after I opened an issue) worked like a charm for me

Answer (score 1):

The answers import the entire `crypto-js` library, thus bloating the app if you only use small bits of it.

I want to keep my app as trim as possible, so this is my approach:

**install via NPM**

```
npm install core-js@3.1.6
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
System.config({
    map:{
        'crypto-js':  'node_modules/crypto-js',
        ...
    },
    packages:{
        'crypto-js': {main: './index.js', defaultExtension: 'js', format: 'cjs'},
        ...
    }
});
```

**component.ts**

```
//only the core + the modules you need
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js/core';
import 'crypto-js/sha1';
```

This has a couple of drawbacks though. The shortcut methods don't work for me:

**doesn't work**

```
let hash = CryptoJS.SHA1('abcdefghi'); // CryptoJS.SHA1 is undefined
```

**works**

```
let sha1 = CryptoJS.algo.SHA1.create();
sha1.update("abcdefghi");
let hash = sha1.finalize();
```

To avoid the compiler error `"Could not find module x"`, I needed to add the following to a **custom.typings.d.ts**

```
declare module 'crypto-js/core'
```

Then link to the typings from my **main.ts**

```
///<reference path="./app/custom.typings.d.ts"/>
```

The main drawback is that the typings mentioned in the other answers don't seem to work with this approach because they are for the whole `crypto-js` library. For instance, `CryptoJS.algo` is not recognized. So it really sucks but I don't have intellisense/autocomplete in the IDE

So why put with such a drawback? Whereas the whole library adds about 60kb of minified JS to my app, importing just what I need adds 4.5kb. And that's a win for me.

Answer (score 1):

To install cryptojs package run following command:

npm install crypto-js --save

After completing above installation if you are using webpack/bundles or updated angularjs versions then run following command as well to get the declaration files.

npm install --save @types/crypto-js

In @types of node_modules d.ts files will be added so as to resolve import related error for cryptojs. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to run:

typings install --ambient crypto-js

I got the error:

typings ERR! deprecated The "ambient" flag is deprecated. Please use "global" instead

Instead, putting this line in typings.json file, it worked.

"crypto-js": "registry:dt/crypto-js#3.1.4+20160505170201"